# Android TimeoutException connecting to maps.googleapis.com

Tags: java, android, networking, google-api

I'm working on an android app that use google apis services.

When i make a request using wifi at home everything works fine but when I'm in the enterprise network the request fails.

**logcat extraction**

```
03-12 09:51:36.279: W/System.err(1213): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed          
to connect to maps.googleapis.com/74.125.132.95 (port 443) after 20000ms 03-12                           
09:51:36.299: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
03-12 09:51:36.379: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-12 09:51:36.389: W/System.err(1213): at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-12 09:51:36.389: W/System.err(1213): at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-12 09:51:36.399: W/System.err(1213): at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
03-12 09:51:36.410: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
03-12 09:51:36.410: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
03-12 09:51:36.410: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
03-12 09:51:36.419: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
03-12 09:51:36.419: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
03-12 09:51:36.430: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
03-12 09:51:36.430: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
03-12 09:51:36.479: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442 )
03-12 09:51:36.489: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
03-12 09:51:36.489: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
03-12 09:51:36.489: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
03-12 09:51:36.509: W/System.err(1213): at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
03-12 09:51:36.509: W/System.err(1213): at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:90)
03-12 09:51:36.520: W/System.err(1213): at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:895)
03-12 09:51:36.530: W/System.err(1213): at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.GooglePlaces.search(GooglePlaces.java:63)
03-12 09:51:36.530: W/System.err(1213): at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:183)
03-12 09:51:36.530: W/System.err(1213): at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
03-12 09:51:36.582: W/System.err(1213): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-12 09:51:36.589: W/System.err(1213): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-12 09:51:36.589: W/System.err(1213): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-12 09:51:36.599: W/System.err(1213): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-12 09:51:36.609: W/System.err(1213): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-12 09:51:36.620: D/AndroidRuntime(1213): Shutting down VM
03-12 09:51:36.620: W/dalvikvm(1213): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces$1.run(MainActivity.java:209)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4644)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:203)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-12 09:51:36.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 09:56:36.880: I/Process(1213): Sending signal. PID: 1213 SIG: 9
```

I've already googled but I didn't had any useful solution. I try to increase the connection timeout but with no luck.

Really have no idea what is causing the problem because the wifi of the entreprise works fine but for this website: `maps.googleapis.com`.

Comment: there may be a firewall in the enterprise network preventing access to the website

Comment: Actually no, there is no firewall or any proxy filtering! I tried to increase the connection time out and also get the same error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I was working behiend a proxy I've done this steps and after that I haven't got this error:

1. To know wich proxy I was behind I used this post https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using
2. in the emulator I went to Wireless & network settings" --> "Mobile networks" --> "Access point names and I set up the proxy name with port that I found in wpad.dat file
3. On Run Configuration> Android Application > App > Target > Additional Emulator Command Line Options: -http-proxy http://:

I hope that it will help someone!

Comment: Can you explain how you fixed the issue from occurring in the app? Adding a command line option for the emulator won't help the production app, will it?